# grails: how to bind data to GroovyPagesTemplateEngine instance?

Tags: templates, grails

I tried to bind data to a template created using GroovyPagesTemplateEngine, but cannot.
Here is what I can as far I can go.  Could some one help?  Thanks!

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPagesTemplateEngine
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource

File myfile = new File("c:\\myTools\\mydata.gsp")
def engine = new GroovyPagesTemplateEngine()

def data = ['data':'test']       

def template = engine.createTemplate(new FileSystemResource(myfile))
```

I tried template.make(data), but does not work.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine

def engine = new SimpleTemplateEngine()
String templateContent = new File('c:/myTools/mydata.gsp').text
def binding = [data: 'test']

String rendered = engine.createTemplate(templateContent).make(binding).toString()
```

Comment: Yes, that works. However, when I tried to use taglibs. I cannot access them. I thought I could use GroovyPagesTemplateEngine to solve my problem. Do you know how to access taglibs using SimpleTemplateEnine?  thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
def templateText = """
  <h1>Hello $who</h1>
"""
def output = new StringWriter()
groovyPagesTemplateEngine.createTemplate(templateText, 'sample').make([who:'World']).writeTo(output)
render output.toString()
```

Just include groovyPagesTemplateEngine via dependency injection, the same way you would reference a service.